# How to block internet explorer on my Django web app?

Tags: django, html, internet-explorer

I'm working on a web application that does not work well with Internet Explorer (web socket, json, security issues).

For now, before my application works with IE:

**How can I refuse connections coming from Internet Explorer client ?**

Thank you

Comment: Please don't do this. Give them a nice message saying that your app is incompatible and encourage them to use a new browser or install chrome frame.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect Browser type in Django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669294/how-to-detect-browser-type-in-django)

Comment: I'd normally agree with Nick, but as it's IE, [just kill their browser](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/33394/how-to-crash-any-version-of-internet-explorer-with-simple-html/)

Comment: `<!--[if IE]>
<div class="error">This service is currently incompatible with Internet Explorer. Please use another browser until we can correct the issue. We apologize for the inconvenience.
<![endif]-->` - a warning would be good, so they can at least see what it looks like. If you want to be blunt, you can do something like `<!--[if IE]> <!-- <![endif]-->` (your page content) `<!--[if IE]> --> <![endif]-->` which should effectively comment out your whole code if the browser is IE. I wouldn't recommend being THAT blunt though.

Comment: @NickTomlin Do not you think that the frustration will be greater if a user still try my application? I want to display a message and refuse the connection. Is it really bad?

Answer (score 4):

Create a middleware where you're parsing the `request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`. If you found that the user use IE, give him a nice message (e.g a notification or a little alert box) to says him that your site isn't optimized for his browser :)

#### Some code example: Django way

middleware.py [(see the doc for more information)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/)

```
class RequestMiddleware():
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.META.has_key('HTTP_USER_AGENT'):
            user_agent = request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].lower()
            if 'trident' in user_agent or 'msie' in user_agent:
                 request.is_IE = True
            else:
                 request.is_IE = False

           # or shortest way:
           request.is_IE = ('trident' in user_agent) or ('msie' in user_agent)
```

your base template:

```
{% if request.is_IE %}<div class="alert">Watch out! You're using IE, but unfortunately, this website need HTML5 features...</div>{% endif %}
```

And then add it to your middlewares list.

#### Optimized: pure HTML way

If you only want to display a message like what I've done, you can use a HTML conditional comment:

```
<!--[if IE]> <div class="alert">...</div><![endif]-->
```

Comment: shouldn't this be `MISE` instead of `Trident` ?

Comment: @psychok7 Indeed, `MSIE` is more frequent than `Trident` in User Agent strings: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Internet%20Explorer/ I'm going to fix it

Comment: [According to Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(VS.85).aspx): `As of Internet Explorer 10, conditional comments are no longer supported by standards mode. Use feature detection to provide effective fallback strategies for website features that aren't supported by the browser.`

Answer (score 4):

There is another way! Just use settings variable [DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#std:setting-DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS), and make sure that [CommonMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.common) is installed on your site.

For example

```
import re
DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS = (re.compile(r'msie\s*[2-7]', re.IGNORECASE), )
```

Cheers!

Comment: please put an example of using  DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS

Comment: is it possible to change default 403 message on that level?

Comment: I guess yes, since Django 1.9 raises a PermissionDenied exception
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.9/#requests-and-responses
so, you can change default handler403
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views